# Use of Meter in Android App

Tags: android

can any one tell me about this problem? I have an two image one image is frame and other image is mask and i want to use it like frame fill with the mask with respect to result of some kind of calculation.e.g result is 60 then then frame also fill with the masks but not full but 60% fill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use clip drawable for doing that. Have a look at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html.

Comment: Please tell me about the above problem.By means that how can i handle the above problem in java file(programatically)?